# Message-driven Beans in Open Liberty 19.0.0.3 do not activate when accessing ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic, websphere-liberty, message-driven-bean

I've got an OpenLiberty application server accessing Active MQ 5.15.18 via a Resource adapter, but I'm not able to properly configure the activation spec so the MDB is activated when a new message comes in.

The application is able to put messages in the output queue, however, the MDB is not activated when a new messages arrive in the input queue. The same code works on locally created queues over the embedded local provider (WLP as the JMS server, no ActiveMQ involved).

I've tried several code snippets cherry picked over stack overflow, my problem seems pretty much like [WebSphere Liberty ActiveMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481153/websphere-liberty-activemq) but the same recipee is not working for me.

This is my MDB code:

```
@MessageDriven(name = "MyMDB",
        activationConfig = {  
           @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Queue"),  
           @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="destination", propertyValue="APP1_QIN"),  
           @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="acknowledgeMode", propertyValue="Auto-acknowledge")  
        })
public class MyMDB implements MessageListener {

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("Init MDB");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("Message received in MDB: " + message);
    }

    @Resource
    MessageDrivenContext ejbcontext;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void setMessageDrivenContext(EJBContext ejbcontext) {
    }

}
```

Below my server.xml:

```
<server description="defaultServer">
    <featureManager>
        <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jca-1.7</feature>
    </featureManager>

    ...

    <resourceAdapter id="ActiveMQResourceAdapter" location="/path/to/libs/activemq-rar-5.15.8.rar">
        <properties.ActiveMQResourceAdapter ServerUrl="tcp://localhost:61616" />
    </resourceAdapter>

    <jmsQueueConnectionFactory connectionManagerRef="QueueConnMgr" jndiName="jms/QCF">  
        <properties.ActiveMQResourceAdapter />      
    </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>    

    <jmsQueue id="APP1_QIN" jndiName="jms/APP1_QIN">
        <properties.ActiveMQResourceAdapter PhysicalName="APP1_QIN" />
    </jmsQueue>

    <jmsQueue id="APP1_QOUT" jndiName="jms/APP1_QOUT">
        <properties.ActiveMQResourceAdapter PhysicalName="APP1_QOUT" />
    </jmsQueue>

     <jmsActivationSpec id="MyMDB">     
        <properties.ActiveMQResourceAdapter/> <!--  destination="APP1_QIN"   -->
    </jmsActivationSpec>

    <connectionManager id="QueueConnMgr" maxPoolSize="5"/>
</server>
```

I would expect the MDB to properly activate as soon as the messages come in, but it doesn't. Also, looking at the ActiveMQ console there seem to be zero consumers over this queue.

Any ideas?

Comment: `MyMDB` has 2 instances of the `@MessageDriven` annotation. Is that intended?

Comment: According to the EJB specification the `destinationType` activation configuration property should be either `javax.jms.Topic` or `javax.jms.Queue`. Therefore, I don't think `org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue` would be considered valid.

Comment: Thanks @JustinBertram it was actually a leftover code from a previous test. I've amended the code above. I'm trying actuallly with one notation and javax.jms.Queue as the destination type, same result.

Comment: If it works with local ActiveMQ queue, then it might be network related. Check if you have any firewall set up between Liberty and AMQ. Also your shown config has localhost (but it is probably from your older test) - `ServerUrl="tcp://localhost:61616"`

Comment: It works with JMS queues locally hosted inside WLP (being WLP the queue provider). It does not work with Active MQ in the equation. It's running on localhost so no firewall involved.

Also I can put and get messages in the queue (explicitly), the only issue is that the MDB doesn't activate.

Comment: In that case check the logs if Active spec is actually initialized or if there are some errors. Looks like your AS id might be incorrect, it should be in the following form: `<activationSpec id="app1/module1/MyMessageDrivenBean">`

Comment: That was it! Thanks @Gas

Comment: Please don't add things like SOLVED to a question title, and preferably don't add the solution to your question body either. If you managed to solve you problem, then either accept the answer that helped you fix it, or post your own **answer** with your solution and accept it after the timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your AS id might be incorrect, it should be in the following form: `<activationSpec id="app1/module1/MyMessageDrivenBean">` with the correct name of the application, module and message driven bean.

Check more details for configuring AS here [Configuring JCA activation specifications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_jca_config_actspec.html)